# HTML to DOM mouse cursor, change background and text colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Please help my task is: when you move the mouse cursor on the selected item, change the background and text colors

http://liveweave.com/rVjF5y

Comment: Can you show us only the relevant code in the question here on SO? That way we don't have to worry about external sites being slow or down.

Answer (score 2):

You can add below CSS code

```
.lw:hover { background-color: red; color:  blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in css using the :hover, example:

```css
.element1 {
padding: 4px;
display: block;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
.element1:hover {
background: #d1d1d1;
color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">Mouse Over / Mouse Out</div>
```